# I need to import a class from another program in python

Tags: python, class

```
class memory:
# This calss is the memory reading and indexing part 
def __init__(self, memsave, memrestore, x, x1):
    self.x = x
    self.x1 = x1
    self.memsave = memsave
    self.memrestore = memrestore
    x = []
    x1 = []

def getx(self, QAtoget):
    filepathx1 = question_memory_value
    # The try checks to see if the Question Exists
    try:
        open(filepathx1)
    except ValueError:
        open(filepathx1, "w+")
    x = []
    # This opens the Question file to get all of the saved values
    with open(filepathx1) as fp:
        linex1 = fp.readline()
        count = 1
        while linex1:
            x.append(linex1.strip())
            linex1 = fp.readline()
            count += 1

    QAtoget = ">>>" + QAtoget
    print(QAtoget)
    print(x)
    if QAtoget in x:
        #This is the indexing part `itemplacement` is the varable that shows what entry the question is on
        itemplacement = x.index(QAtoget)
        return itemplacement
    else:
        return False
def findvalue(self, numlist):
    x1 = []
    #This is the file read in part where we see the memory that is stored
    filepathx2 = answer_memory_value
    with open(filepathx2) as fp:
        linex2 = fp.readline()
        count = 1
        while linex2:
            x1.append(linex2.strip())
            linex2 = fp.readline()
            count += 1
    #This is condesing the >>>QUESTION to just QUESTION
    returningvaluecondence = x1[numlist]
    memoryvaluecondeser = returningvaluecondence[3:len(returningvaluecondence)]
    return memoryvaluecondeser
```

That is the class
I need to run the class funtions from another python program, and it needs to be portable so no explicit folder names, but they will all be in the same folder.

How would I run `memory.getx("", Question)` from another program

Answer (score 0):

Classes need to start with a capital letter.

```
class Memory:
....code...
```

To use a class in another program you just need to import the file name
like this:

```
import filename

mymemory = filename.Memory()
```

Comment: classes do not need to start with a capital letter though that is a common convention. `dict` for example is a class that does not start with a capital letter.